# Why does `snakemake --list-untracked ...` list the `config.yaml` file in its output?

Tags: snakemake

I'm learning snakemake and tried running my command with the `--list-untracked` option to see if I had any unaccounted for leftover outputs or unused inputs, like this:

```
snakemake --cores 12 --use-conda --directory test_data/small_fastq_samples/ --list-untracked
```

I found some abandoned reference inputs that I neglected to delete, but I also saw my config file in there too:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
config.yml
input/reference/gen.1.bt2
input/reference/gen.2.bt2
input/reference/gen.3.bt2
input/reference/gen.4.bt2
input/reference/gen.rev.1.bt2
input/reference/gen.rev.2.bt2
```

This surprised me, because the workflow reads from that config file:

```
configfile: "config.yml"
SAMPLES = config["sample_names"]
REFNAME = config["reference_name"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("results/sorted_atac_alignments/QC/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.{ext}", sample=SAMPLES, ext=["zip", "html"]),
        expand("results/sorted_atac_alignments/{sample}.bam", sample=SAMPLES)
```

Have I made a mistake somewhere or is this intended behavior?

The [doc](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#utilities) doesn't seem to explain why it would list the config file.  It suggests that it only lists files that are not used in the workflow:

> `--list-untracked, --lu`
>
> List all files in the working directory that are not used in the workflow. This can be used e.g. for identifying leftover files. Hidden files and directories are ignored.
>
> Default: False

Assuming I don't have a mistake somewhere (because the workflow works as intended), what's the reasoning behind designating the config file as "not used"?

#### Additional Notes

If I run `snakemake --lint` from the main repo directory, I see:

```
WorkflowError in file /Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/ATACCOMPENDIUM/REPOS/ATACCompendium/Snakefile, line 3:
Workflow defines configfile config.yml but it is not present or accessible (full checked path: /Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/ATACCOMPENDIUM/REPOS/ATACCompendium/config.yml).
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/ATACCOMPENDIUM/REPOS/ATACCompendium/Snakefile", line 3, in <module>
```

Though maybe the `--lint` utility isn't meant to be used on the main repo directory?  If I run `snakemake --lint --directory test_data/small_fastq_samples/`, I see:

```
Congratulations, your workflow is in a good condition!
```

I'm still trying to get the hang of this.  Is there a way to lint the codebase without having a dataset directory to run?

Given inferences I made from the linting output, I tried editing my rules file's `all` rule to include `config.yml`:

```
rule all:
    input:
        "config.yml",
        expand("results/sorted_atac_alignments/QC/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.{ext}", sample=SAMPLES, ext=["zip", "html"]),
        expand("results/sorted_atac_alignments/{sample}.bam", sample=SAMPLES)
```

Now, if I run the command (as above) with `--list-untracked`, it does not output the `config.yml`:

```
$ snakemake --cores 12 --use-conda --directory test_data/small_fastq_samples/ --lint
Congratulations, your workflow is in a good condition!
```

So that seems to work.  Is that bad practice?  Or is there any reason/convention I shouldn't include the config file among the inputs?

Comment: Is your working directory the current directory?  If so, this seems to be correct though perhaps not intended.  I expect snakemake is looking at all the files in the working directory and seeing which it can produce with rules in the snakefile.

Comment: That was my guess, but I just tried running `snakemake --lint` and it complains that `Workflow defines configfile config.yml but it is not present or accessible`. I don't understand that because I can run the workflow just fine. It would presumably fail without it, because that's where the samples and reference are defined...

Comment: And to confirm, yes, the config file is in the working directory. But oddly, the path in the error says `full checked path: /Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/ATACCOMPENDIUM/REPOS/ATACCompendium/config.yml`. That's *NOT* the working directory. That's the repo's main directory... Something's screwy.

Comment: Judging from the [implementation](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/2558ea53ecc116faaa6b515d452a1fde3fa2b400/snakemake/dag.py#L2396-L2416), I think the `config.yaml` file was simply missed during implementing this helper function. You could open an issue in the snakemake GitHub repository. As for your second question: *I would consider adding `config.yaml` as input to `rule all` a bad practice if there is not real dependency*, i.e. if you to get rid of the `--lint` message.

Comment: @euronion Thanks. The docstring of that linked method does suggest that it's only for files *not in the dag*. Also, by "if there is no real dependency", are you suggesting that the workflow could run successfully without `config.yml`? Does that mean that there exists a way to get around the error issued when the line: `configfile: "config.yml"` fails?

Comment: No, usually you cannot run a workflow without the `config.yml`. I meant the dependency in the `rule all`. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [current implementation](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/2558ea53ecc116faaa6b515d452a1fde3fa2b400/snakemake/dag.py#L2396-L2416) of `snakemake --list-untracked` only considers files which are part of your current DAG as `input`, `output` or `log` as "tracked". All other files are considered "untracked" and therefore reported.

Adding your `configfile` as a dummy dependency to a rule like `rule all` only to get rid of the error message is something *I would personally consider bad practice* as it obfuscates dependencies. It could be misunderstood as a real dependency (e.g. the `configfile` could be required and accessed directly by the rule = real dependency).

Personally I would just ignore it.

If you want don't want `config.yml` to show up in the list of untracked files, I suggest you add a dummy rule with that sole purpose of tracking "untracked files", e.g.:

```py
configfile: "config.yml"

# Include all files you want considered "tracked" by snakemake
rule track_files:
    input:
        "config.yml"

# This is the default_target rule which is executed if snakemake
# is called without a rule name or file name as target
rule all:
    input:
        # Make tracked files part of your DAG
        rules.track_files.input
    default_target: True
    shell:
        "echo 'hello world'"
```

This way your intention of including the dependency becomes clear. You can also add more files to the `track_files` rule. Note:

1. `rule track_files` has to be defined before `rule all`, else the `rules.track_files.input` can not be resolved
2. `default_target: True` in `rule all` makes sure that rule is always run if snakemake is called without an explicit target
3. If you call `snakemake --list-untracked` `snakemake` considers the DAG for the default rule, in your case `all`. If you provide a different rule or file as target, all files which are not part of that specific DAG will be reported as "untracked".